# Is there any way to display a bitmap from a .NET Core Console application?

Tags: .net-core, bitmap

Is there any way to display a bitmap from a .NET Core Console application?

My application reads a bitmap using [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp), but I would like to visualize it. Is there any trick to do so? Since .NET Core doesn't handle graphics as far as I know.

Comment: You could display it in ASCII, but why would you want to do that? The only alternative is to fire up a UI of some sort.

Comment: @DavidG Unfortunately, there's no UI framework capable of running off .NET Core, apart from [Avalonia](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia), and I don't know how to convert a bitmap from ImageSharp to Avalonia.

Comment: .NET Core 3 has WinForms and WPF.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, but it's not cross-platform.

Comment: There is no cross-platform solution unless you use Avalonia for example. But, I don;t understand why you have a console app but also want a UI.

Comment: @DavidG For simplicity. I just want to show the image instead of writing it to disk. It's an application for a workshop. Thanks anyways :)